# showing blank page after building reactjs with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have three parts on my project and I use react-router-dom for pages. whenever I start project on developement mood, There's no problem. But when I generate build, It shows a blank page,though I have no error.I checked link of Javascript and CSS files, They work properly.I'm using apache for web server.
I enabled mod-rewrite and its code is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

My definition for react-router-dom  is as follows:

```
        <Router history={history}>
        <Route
          exact
          path='/'
          component={()=><Home i18n={i18n} />}
        />
        <Route
          path='/cancel'
          component={()=><Cancel i18n={i18n} />}
        />
        <Route
          path='/success'
          component={()=><TransactionData i18n={i18n} />}
        />
    </Router>
```

Comment: What happens if you go to each route from browser url

Comment: @JohnSnow It shows me not found.

Comment: Try changing `component={()=><Home i18n={i18n} />}` to `render={()=><Home i18n={i18n} />}`.

Comment: sometimes it happens because of the catching mechanism on the server. Are you sure the server's cache is not dirty? Could you modify public/index.html and see what happens?